# NamedQueries Spring using LIKE % %

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, entitymanager

I just want to code a simple search engine.

In my DAO implementation :

```
@Transactional(readOnly=true)
    public List<Thread> findAllWithReferer(String referer) {
        Map<String, Object> params = new TreeMap<String, Object>();

        log.debug("DAO:findAllWithReferer(String referer) - referer=" + referer);
        params.put("referer", "%" + referer + "%");
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List<Thread> threads = EntityManagerUtil.executeNamedQueryInTransaction("Thread.findAllWithReferer", params);
        return (threads);
    }
```

Utils class providing the method 'executeNamedQueryInTransaction' above:

```
@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    public static List executeNamedQueryInTransaction(String queryName, Map<String, Object> params) {
        EntityManager em = createEntityManagerAndOpenTransaction();
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery(queryName);

        for (String key : params.keySet())
            query.setParameter(key, params.get(key));

        List l = query.getResultList();
        commitTransactionAndCloseEntity(em);

        return l;
    }
```

And the Namedquery linked to my entity :

```
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Thread.findAllWithReferer", query = "SELECT t FROM Thread t WHERE t.title LIKE :referer")
})
```

I just want to match all records with, for exemple, the string 'toto' in my entity title field using the operator % % in my DAO.

Here's some exemple that could match :

toto is great
Doestotois great ?
dghjgdjtotojdashkjdhk

But it does not work. Just the exact string works.
I want to precise that the code into 'executeNamedQueryInTransaction' method is correct and works perfectly. I think my problem comes from here :

```
params.put("referer", "%" + referer + "%");
```

Does anyone can help me, please ?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just try this`params.put("referer", '%' + referer.toLowerCase() + '%');`.
Replace double quotes by simple quotes.